# BackgroundWorker control doesn't display the percentage progress

Tags: .net, vb.net, progress-bar, backgroundworker, percentage

I'm trying to display the percentage progress on my progress bar called `ProgressBar1`, now have create a `BackGrounWorker` called `BkW1` and I have this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       BKW1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BKW1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BKW1.DoWork
      ExternalClass.MyFunction() 'This function is located in another class
End Sub

Private Sub BKW1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BKW1.ProgressChanged
      Invoke(Sub()
               ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
             End Sub)
End Sub
```

Now my `ExternalClass.MyFunction()` iterate through all records available on a `DataTable` and that's it. Why thee BackGroundWorker doesn't display the percentage on my ProgressBar1? I should insert some reference in my external function?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify that the BackgroundWorker actually displays the progress (so in `Form_Load`):

```
BKW1.WorkerReportsProgress= True
```

Then you have to actually tell it to report the progress in the `DoWork` method (this fires the `ProgressChanged` event):

```
BKW1.ReportProgress(x)
```

So you may need to get `ExternalClass` to raise a `ProgressChanged` event and call this line there. Here is a simplified example:

```
Public Class ExternalClass
    Public Event ProgressChanged(percentage As Integer)

    Public Function MyFunction() As Boolean
        For i As Integer = 0 To 100
            'do something
            'report the progress
            RaiseEvent ProgressChanged(i)
        Next
        Return True
    End Function
End Class

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim MyExternalClass As New ExternalClass
    AddHandler MyExternalClass.ProgressChanged, Sub(x) ExternalClass_ProgressChanged(x)
    MyExternalClass.MyFunction
End Sub

Private Sub ExternalClass_ProgressChanged(percentage As Integer)
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

Note that you don't actually need to invoke the method in the `BKW1_ProgressChanged` event as this runs on the UI thread. This is the reason why the `BackgroundWorker` is more convenient to use.

Comment: So I should execute BKW1.ReportProgress(x) in my ExternalClass.MyFunction()?

Comment: No - raise an event in that class that you handler in your form. I have posted some example code

Comment: Okay now the event is fired but e.ProgressPercentage return even 0 why?

Comment: Check that you are setting the correct value in the external class

Comment: I found the problem, some times I have 1 record to iterate in my datatable, so the x (index) is equal to 0. I also tried to set my _ExternalClass.ProgressBar1.Maximum = DataTable.Tables(0).Rows.Count but the percentage still remain on 0

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried to raise the event ReportProgress() in the Sub BKW1_DoWork on every loop? Otherwise the event ProgressChanged will not be fired.

Here some interesting code that might help you: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_use_backgroundworker.html